# Installing edubuntu alongside win10

Tags: interface, uefi

My new DELL laptop (barely few weeks old) has come with pre-installed Win10 64Bit version and it has new UEFI booting system. I would like to install EdUbuntu alongside with Win10 and with a graphical boot option menu. I have tried following steps -

1) Downloaded all 5 images of EdUbuntu and copied them on a 32GB FlashDrive using Win32 DiskManager tool. It allows me to try EdUbuntu and am quite happy with it. (Followed all steps to disable Fastboot from Power Menu and then turned on Legacy BIOS in BIOS setup Menu.

2) I now have several partitions using Disk Management tool. One of them is not formatted 136GB (to allow EdUbuntu) to be installed.

3) I followed all steps listed elsewhere on this forum and elsewhere where I could format the unformatted disk partition during EdUbuntu install process.

4) I could manage to install EdUbuntu.

Problems encountered: I needed a graphical interface to popup during boot process which allows me to see and select either Win10 and EdUbuntu

Steps taken so far:
I downloaded EasyBCD and installed it. However, during making changes on Linux tab - it does not allow me to do anything. Everytime I start EasyBCD it shows a message that it has detected UEFI and some of its capabilities will not be available.

I tried having legacy BIOS menu (instead of Windows Boot loader) and this turned my entire laptop upside down with no option to boot into Win10. Every time it boots, it boots into EdUbuntu.

Luckily I have had taken an image (Ghost) of entire disk before installing EdUbuntu and am in the process of first killing the disk using KillDisk and then reinstating Win10 image on hard drive.

Now, am really scared whether I will get my original Win10 or not?

My queries:

A) I will be very happy if experts among you, who have tried getting a graphical boot interface, can help me out? If so, how do I go about it?

B) Is it something I need to do while computer boots into EdUbuntu? Please be very specific with detailed steps.

Thanking ALL of you for taking time to read this post.

Virendra

Comment: Phew! , lot of steps. I see what I can do.

Comment: *AFAIK* you only need *one* disk image to install the system. It would help if you provided a clear view of the *Partition Table* of your disk and exactly *what* are you seeing when you boot your system: you stated what you expected, not what you encountered. Moreover, it would help if you included the **steps** that you followed, in particular the partitioning and boot-loader installation steps. Please **edit** your question with the necessary information.

Comment: Dear Patrick - a lot has happened since then. My laptop is a total brick as of now. I am not sure how I can view Partition Table? How do I go about viewing Partition Table - sorry for my ignorance in current circumstances